# Laravel Eloquent many to many filter on intermediate table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I'm using a User/Post example in the question. I have two tables Users and Posts linked together with a many to many relationship with post_views as table. Also I've created an Event and Listener to handle the views on a post. But I only want to add a new view-entry if the last view for a given post was over an hour ago by that user.

At the moment my `handle()` method in the `UpdatePostViews` listener does:

```
public function handle(PostWasViewed $event)
{
    $event->post->views()->attach($event->user->id);
}
```

The relationship is defined with `withTimestamps` But how can I filter in the `handle()` method to do something like

```
    $lastView = User::where('user_id', $userId)
->where('post_id', $postId)
->in('post_views')
->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
->first();
```

which would return the last row for a user/post combination from the `post_views` so I can determine on the timestamps it was inserted over an hour ago and add a new entry or skip creation of a new entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `wherePivot` method on the `BelongsToMany` relationship to add constraints on the pivot table for the query.

Once you do that, you can use any combination of logic to determine if there was a view in the last hour. Something like:

```
public function handle(PostWasViewed $event)
{
    $inLastHour = $event->user->posts()->where('id', $event->post->id)->wherePivot('updated_at', '>=', new \Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression('NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR'))->exists();

    // or, either way, shouldn't matter

    $inLastHour = $event->post->views()->where('id', $event->user->id)->wherePivot('updated_at', '>=', new \Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression('NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR'))->exists();

    if (!$inLastHour) {
        $event->post->views()->attach($event->user->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's also a nice solution to the problem. Accepted your answer, feels stupid to accept my own answer to my own question ;) The user, in my case, is already present in the $event object. Thanks! +1

Comment: you were right in your comments to my answer. I've deleted my own answer since it's a wrong one. Thanks for further explaining!